# turn negative number to imaginary

Tags: python, math

I am making a program that can calculate the resolution of a quadratic equation. This works when the discriminant `d` is non-negative, but not for complex roots.

How can I insert a imaginary square root?

```
import math
a = input("insert the value of a: ")
b = input("insert the value of b: ")
c = input("insert the value of c: ")
def d(a,b,c) : return (b**2)-(4.*a*c)
def x1(d,a,b,c) : return (b-(2.*b))+(math.sqrt ( d ))/2.*a
def x2(d,a,b,c) : return (b-(2.*b))-(math.sqrt ( d ))/2.*a
print ("the values of D,X' e X'' respectively: ")
print (d(a,b,c),x1(d,a,b,c),x2(d,a,b,c))
```

Also, when I use `a=4 b=4 c=1` and `d` was going to be `0`, I get the following error.  I'm not sure what's wrong here.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python27/equation2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (d(a,b,c),x1(d,a,b,c),x2(d,a,b,c))
  File "H:/Python27/equation2.py", line 6, in x1
    def x1(d,a,b,c) : return (b-(2.*b))+(math.sqrt ( d ))/2.*a
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer and explain result you'd expect?

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to take the sqrt of a function.  The function name does *not* automatically represent the result of the most recent call.  Try a temporary variable:

```
d_result = d(a,b,c)
print (d_result, x1(d_result,a,b,c), x2(d_result,a,b,c))
```

This fixes only the fatal error; the immediate problem is still that you don't handle complex roots.  **Note:** for your given case of a=b=c=4, the discriminant is -48, *not* 0, as your posting states.

Here, you have two courses:

1. Read the documentation on complex numbers available in Python
2. Write the complex parts yourself: take the sqrt of abs(d_result), save that as the imaginary part, and compute the real part separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help... im really new at all this coding things.